# Data Caching chances of returning null value from function

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I have a function written in C# which return collection of business-entity (make) after checking and inserting in cache.

```
  public static Collection<CProductMakesProps> GetCachedSmartPhoneMake(HttpContext context)
    {
        var allMake = context.Cache["SmartPhoneMake"] as Collection<CProductMakesProps>;
        if (allMake == null)
        {
            context.Cache.Insert("SmartPhoneMake", new CModelRestrictionLogic().GetTopMakes(), null,
                                 DateTime.Now.AddHours(Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MakeCacheTime"])),
                                 Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);

            allMake = context.Cache["SmartPhoneMake"] as Collection<CProductMakesProps>;
        }
        return allMake;
    }
```

I am using it in some other page as follows

```
 var lobjprodMakeCol = CBrandCache.GetCachedSmartPhoneMake(Context);
 //CBrandCache is the class which contain the method
```

Is it possible that I get null value in the `lobjprodMakeCol`

Thanks.

---

Edit

Note `new CModelRestrictionLogic().GetTopMakes()` is a function which fetches the records from database.
It will return a collection weather of count 0 or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few of possibilities when your function could return null - they are

1. `GetTopMakes` function it self returns null
2. The cache expiration time is zero (`MakeCacheTime` config entry has zero value)
3. The cast `as Collection<CProductMakesProps>` fails - possible if `GetTopMakes`
   return some different type.

I would prefer below version which would not return null in all of above cases

```
var allMake = context.Cache["SmartPhoneMake"] as Collection<CProductMakesProps>;
if (allMake == null)
{
   allMake = new CModelRestrictionLogic().GetTopMakes();
   context.Cache.Insert("SmartPhoneMake", allMake, 
      null, DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(Int32.Parse(
      ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MakeCacheTime"])), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
}
return allMake;
```

Also note that use of `DateTime.UtcNow` that would avoid any surprises such as day-light savings etc.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion and answer. But I would like to know is there any difference between your and @slugster approach?

Comment: @krshekhar, as I said, above code wouldn't return null even if cache expiration time is zero (indicating that no caching is required). On side note, it eliminates an unnecessary cache look-up in cache-miss scenario but that really does not matter in scheme of things! Further, you can further re-factor above code to read the cache expiration time from config in static constructor but again...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, if the cast `as Collection<CProductMakesProps>` fails then a null will be assigned to `allMake`, so this depends heavily on what you are returning from `new CModelRestrictionLogic().GetTopMakes()`.

Based on the assumption that most cache and/or dictionary collections will allow you to check for the presense of a specific key, I would suggest a slightly more streamlined way of writing this:

```
public static Collection<CProductMakesProps> GetCachedSmartPhoneMake(HttpContext context)
{
    if (!context.Cache.ContainsKey("SmartPhoneMake") || context.Cache["SmartPhoneMake"] == null)
    {
        context.Cache.Insert("SmartPhoneMake"
                             , new CModelRestrictionLogic().GetTopMakes()
                             , null
                             , DateTime.Now.AddHours(Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MakeCacheTime"]))
                             , Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
    }

    return context.Cache["SmartPhoneMake"] as Collection<CProductMakesProps>;
}
```

Comment: if the cast as `Collection<CProductMakesProps>` fails then a null will be assigned to allMake **true** but after that the null check will assign value to the  context.Cache am I right?

Comment: @krshekhar You have two different instances of the cast `as Collection<CProductMakesProps>` in your code, this will (silently) fail and return null if the type it is applied against cannot be cast that way. Your question was *Is it possible that I get null value in the lobjprodMakeCol?*, to which the answer is *yes, it is possible with the way you have the code*.